# tense with "since" when talking about dead people's lives

Tags: present-perfect, since

Is it correct to use the present perfect in the following? If not, how would you revise it?

> Charles Dickens left school to work in a factory and **has since become** a professional writer.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: That is acceptable in both formal written and colloquial spoken English. It is commonly used in job references, as you did.BTW, he has had some success since becoming an author.

Comment: Your sentence is grammatical but it means that Charles Dickens is still a professional writer... is that really what you mean?

Comment: He is dead, of course. I'm wondering whether the present perfect can still be used.

Comment: I think that, grammatically, it is ok. However, I agree that it implies that he is still alive. I would consider saying "Charles Dickens left school to work in a factory and **later** became a professional writer."